# finding the link (href) for a specific child in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href, children

I have strings similar to this:

```
[<tr><td><big>Motion Picture Sound Editors, USA</big></td></tr>, <tr><th>Year</th><th>Result</th><th>Award</th><th>Category/Recipient(s)</th></tr>, <tr><td align="center" rowspan="2" valign="middle"><a href="/Sections/Awards/Motion_Picture_Sound_Editors_USA/2010">2010 </a></td><td align="center" rowspan="2" valign="middle"><b>Nominated</b></td><td align="center" rowspan="2" valign="middle">Golden Reel Award</td><td valign="top">Best Sound Editing - Dialogue and ADR in a Feature Film<a href="/name/nm0613398/">Piero Mura</a> (supervising sound editor)<a href="/name/nm0919527/">Christopher T. Welch</a> (supervising dialogue/adr editor)<a href="/name/nm0270704/">Julie Feiner</a> (dialogue editor)<a href="/name/nm0827953/">Beth Sterner</a> (dialogue editor)<a href="/name/nm2628443/">Judah Getz</a> (adr mixer)</td></tr>, <tr><td valign="top">Best Sound Editing - Music in a Feature Film<a href="/name/nm1084134/">Jen Monnar</a> (supervising music editor)</td></tr>, <tr><td colspan="4"> </td></tr>, <tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffdb" colspan="4" valign="top"></td></tr>]
```

where I am pulling the information:

```
[[u'2010 '], [u'Nominated'], [u'Golden Reel Award'], [u'Best Sound Editing - Dialogue and ADR in a Feature Film', u'Piero Mura', u' (supervising sound editor)', u'Christopher T. Welch', u' (supervising dialogue/adr editor)', u'Julie Feiner', u' (dialogue editor)', u'Beth Sterner', u' (dialogue editor)', u'Judah Getz', u' (adr mixer)']]
```

for each name, I want to get only a certain part the link `nm#######`. Any ideas how I can do this, but keep it so I can relate the name to the nm#? (ie. `Piero Mura` will be associated with `nm0613398`)

I already pull this from it:

```
(u'Motion Picture Sound Editors, USA', u'2010 ', u'Nominated', u'Golden Reel Award', u'Best Sound Editing - Dialogue and ADR in a Feature Film', u'Piero Mura')
(u'Motion Picture Sound Editors, USA', u'2010 ', u'Nominated', u'Golden Reel Award', u'Best Sound Editing - Dialogue and ADR in a Feature Film', u'Christopher T. Welch')
(u'Motion Picture Sound Editors, USA', u'2010 ', u'Nominated', u'Golden Reel Award', u'Best Sound Editing - Dialogue and ADR in a Feature Film', u'Julie Feiner')
(u'Motion Picture Sound Editors, USA', u'2010 ', u'Nominated', u'Golden Reel Award', u'Best Sound Editing - Dialogue and ADR in a Feature Film', u'Beth Sterner')
(u'Motion Picture Sound Editors, USA', u'2010 ', u'Nominated', u'Golden Reel Award', u'Best Sound Editing - Dialogue and ADR in a Feature Film', u'Judah Getz')
(u'Motion Picture Sound Editors, USA', u'2010 ', u'Nominated', u'Golden Reel Award', u'Best Sound Editing - Music in a Feature Film', u'Jen Monnar')
(u'Motion Picture Sound Editors, USA', u'2010 ', u'Nominated', u'Golden Reel Award', u'Best Sound Editing - Music in a Feature Film', u' (supervising music editor)')
```

with this:

```
    award_rows = award_soup.findAll("tr")
    award_data = [[td.findChildren(text=True) for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in award_rows]
    for data in award_data:
        categ = []
        if data == award_data[0]:
            award_show = ''.join(data[0])
        if len(data) == 4 and data != award_data[0]:
            categ = data[3]
            for cat in categ:
                if cat == '&nbsp;':
                    cat = ''
                if cat != categ[0] and len(categ) != 1 and cat[0:2] != ' (':
                    award_shows.append(award_show)
                    years.append(''.join(data[0]))
                    results.append(''.join(data[1]))
                    awards.append(''.join(data[2]))
                    categories.append(''.join(categ[0].replace('&nbsp;','')))
                    recipients.append(cat)
                    print data
                elif cat != categ[0] and len(categ) == 1:
                    award_shows.append(award_show)
                    years.append(''.join(data[0]))
                    results.append(''.join(data[1]))
                    awards.append(''.join(data[2]))
                    categories.append(''.join(categ[0].replace('&nbsp;','')))
                    recipients.append('')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search for all `<a>` links with a substring of `nm` plus digits in it. Extract that part and save as a hash:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('xmlfile', 'r'), 'xml')

data = []
for a in soup.find_all('a', attrs={"href": re.compile("nm\d+")}):
    s = re.search(r'nm\d+', a['href']).group(0)
    data.append({a.text: s})

print(data)
```

It yields:

```
[{'Piero Mura': 'nm0613398'}, 
 {'Christopher T. Welch': 'nm0919527'}, 
 {'Julie Feiner': 'nm0270704'}, 
 {'Beth Sterner': 'nm0827953'}, 
 {'Judah Getz': 'nm2628443'}, 
 {'Jen Monnar': 'nm1084134'}]
```